# How can ı print my input information to inside of the modal?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

Hı, I am making Form project with React. Everything is going well. I want to show the entered values in the modal page. But I do not have any idea about how can ı do that. If you have any idea please help to me. Can you help me please?

This is my contact.js page;

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import ModalComponent from "./ModalComponent/index.js";

const Contact = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [emailValue, setEmailValue] = useState("");
  const [phoneNumberValue, setPhoneValue] = useState("");
  const [countryValue, setCountryValue] = useState("");

  const buttonOnClick = () => {
    if (inputValue === "" || emailValue === "" || phoneNumberValue === "") {
      setShowModal(false);
    } else {
      setShowModal(true);
      setInputValue("");
      setEmailValue("");
      setPhoneValue("");
    }
    console.log(`Form submitted, ${showModal}`);

  }


  return (
    <>
      <div className="main">

        <form >
          <div className="baslik">
            <div className="container center">
              <h1>Contact Form</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="field" >
            <label className="text"> Name And Surname: </label>
            <input type="text" className="form" placeholder="Kerem Kurt" value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)} required />
          </div>

          <div className="field">
            <label className="text"> E-mail: </label>
            <input type="email" className="form" placeholder="udenditfy@gmail.com" value={emailValue} onChange={(e) => setEmailValue(e.target.value)} required />
          </div>

          <div className="field">
            <label className="text"> Phone Number: </label>
            <input type="tel" className="form" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="+905373199437" value={phoneNumberValue} onChange={(e) => setPhoneValue(e.target.value)} required />
          </div>

          <div className="field">
            <label className="text" required > Country: </label>
            <select className="form" placeholder="Turkiye" value={countryValue} onChange={(e) => setCountryValue(e.target.value)}>
              <option value="Turkiye">Turkiye</option>
              <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
              <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
              <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
              <option value="France">France</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <button type="button" className="button" onClick={() => buttonOnClick()}> Enter </button>
        </form>
        {!showModal && (inputValue === "" || emailValue === "" || phoneNumberValue === "") &&
          <div>Hata Var</div>}
      </div>
      <ModalComponent show={showModal} handleClose={() => setShowModal(!showModal)} />
    </>
  );
};
export default Contact;
```

And this is my Modal page, I want to show my values to here;

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


export default function ModalComponent({ show ,handleClose }) {
  // const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  // const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  //const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        backdrop="static"
        keyboard={false}
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Contact Information</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
    
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary">Understood</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. You pass props and bind data to modal markup just as you would any markup. It's fundamental to React.  What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Pass your values as props to the modal. Then you could render them inside the model like { props.value }

```
// component
<ModalComponent props=inputValue show={showModal} handleClose={() => setShowModal(!showModal)} />

// modal
export default function ModalComponent({ props, show, handleClose }) {
```